# Regular expression to ensure all links have target="_blank"

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have a textarea which uses CKEditor to generate HTML. I want to ensure that all links the user enters have their `target="_blank"`. I thought I'd need to do two regex checks: one to replace any `target="..."` to `target="_blank"`, and another to just insert target attribute where target attribute doesn't exist. I'm not making much progress:

```
// where target attribute doesn't exist, add it
preg_replace("/<a(\s*(?!target)([\w\-])+=([\\"\'])[^\\"\']+\3)*\s*\/?>/", "<a target="_blank"$1>", $input_lines);
```

This works in this simple case:

```
<a href="#">one</a> ---> <a target="_blank" href="#">one</a>
```

It does not work for `<a href="#" alt="hello">one</a>`, I'm not sure why but then I don't normally do things this challenging with regular expressions.

Also, how would I replace existing `target="..."` (e.g. `target="_parent`") with strictly `target="_blank`"?

Comment: An HTML/XML parser would probably be better for this, http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php.

Comment: I'm just going to stick this here for one of the best answers of all time on Stack Overflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use PHP DOM with XPATH to set attributes or modify existing ones in all `<a>` tags like this:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<a href="somelink.html" target="_blank"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="alt" title="sometitle" /></a>
<a href="somelink1.php" target="_parent">link_no1</a>
<a href="somelink2.php">link_no2</a>
<a href="someimage.jpg"><img src="image2.png"></a>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/tUvqOa)

Output:

```
<a href="somelink.html" target="_blank"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="alt" title="sometitle"><a href="somelink1.php" target="_blank">link_no1</a><a href="somelink2.php" target="_blank">link_no2</a><a href="someimage.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="image2.png"></a></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach.

First remove all `target="..."` items. Perhaps replace `\btarget="[^"]*"` with nothing or a single space.

Next add the wanted `target="_blank"` items. Perhaps replace `<a` with `<a target="_blank"`.

But beware of these replacing text in unexpected places in the file. As the comments on the question say, it is almost always better to use a proper HTML/XML parser.